# how to specify date format in django while defining models.

Tags: python, sql, django

There is `u"'11/24/2013' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format` error when submitted. should the date field be changed according to `yyyy-mm-dd` or any other solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use YYYY-MM-DD. If you really want to have date strings floating about in a format of your choice, use:

```
datetime.strptime(time_string, "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

to convert them when you need to.

Answer (score 1):

`DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#date-input-formats)) setting specifies the formats used to parse input dates.

The default equals to:

```
(
    '%Y-%m-%d', '%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%y', # '2006-10-25', '10/25/2006', '10/25/06'
    '%b %d %Y', '%b %d, %Y',            # 'Oct 25 2006', 'Oct 25, 2006'
    '%d %b %Y', '%d %b, %Y',            # '25 Oct 2006', '25 Oct, 2006'
    '%B %d %Y', '%B %d, %Y',            # 'October 25 2006', 'October 25, 2006'
    '%d %B %Y', '%d %B, %Y',            # '25 October 2006', '25 October, 2006'
)
```